# Get value of last visible cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am using this formula in cell B1 to get last value of visible cell

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/((SUBTOTAL(3;OFFSET(A2:A10;ROW(A2:A10)-MIN(ROW(A2:A10));0;1)))*(1-ISBLANK(A2:A10)));A2:A10)
```

It works well when cell from A1 to A10 doesn't contain a formula. The problem is that this formula not working when the cell contains a formula with an `if` statement.

For example, when in cell A10 I put the formula `=IF(F1=1;1;"")`, the cell a10 shows blank because the condition is not true - and when I filter data the cell B1 show blank.

Comment: When you filter the data how?  The cell with the formula is, by definition, not blank; so if your filter does not exclude it, it will be returned by your formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

`1-ISBLANK(A2:A10)`

with:

`LEN(A2:A10)>0`

Regards

Comment: This works!  And it's faster than an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some different formula for that purpose. One option (array formula - Ctrl + Shift + Enter):

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MAX(IF(A2:A10="";0;ROW(A2:A10))))
```

another array formula option:

```
=INDEX(A2:A10;MAX(IF(A2:A10="";0;ROW(A2:A10)))-1)
```

Comment: not working when i using filter (it is show last hidden value)